# How to use Eclipse for Jadex Active Components - Getting Started Tutorial - Red Cross Error?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to do the Getting Started Tutorial for Jadex Active Components:
https://github.com/actoron/jadex/blob/master/docs/getting-started/getting-started.md

But when I will do it with Gradle, there is always the red cross on the files and I am unable to run it. When I try to import it as Maven Project, there is no pom.cml file to finish the project, so it does not even get started.

And even when I try to do it without Maven/Gradle there is not the opportunity to run the files as a Java Application. I tried all three methods, but I have different issues in all of them.([https://i.stack.imgur.com/cspST.png[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cspST.png%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6twk.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miLIu.png)https://i.stack.imgur.com/cspST.png)